# How to UNION ALL 2 Tables in Search Button

Tags: php, mysql, union

Good AM/PM Sir/Mam.

i see alot of topics here in stackoverflow regarding the Union ALL statement but it really confuse me to apply it in php. can you help me regarding in this matter i really appreciate your help. thank you very much in advance.

i have this 2 tables **intime** and **outtime**.

they have 2 Columns which is `username` and `details`.

here's my code:

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intime WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`details` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

and this one for the other table.

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM outtime WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`details` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank you Verymuch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM intime 
WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`details` LIKE '%".$query."%') 

UNION ALL 

SELECT * FROM outtime 
WHERE (`username` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`details` LIKE '%".$query."%')");
```

Comment: imma try this now sir sadikhasan.

Comment: What do you mean try?

Comment: thats my problem sir i have no idea to use it in php im kinda new in php and sql :'(

Comment: i got 2 errors Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Comment: i just remove it *""* sir and it works! i will study this statement thank you very much.

Comment: IT WORKS Sir! Thank you so much. i will study the format for php. it really help me. thank you again.